# 'django_postgrespool' isn't an available database backend

Tags: django, django-postgresql

After installing [django_postgrespool](https://github.com/kennethreitz/django-postgrespool) and configuring my project accordingly, I received the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\my_proj\my_module.py", line 14, in <module>
    from cortex.my_app.models import MyModel
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\my_proj\my_app\models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\virtual_environments\spyker\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\virtual_environments\spyker\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\virtual_environments\spyker\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 92, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\virtual_environments\spyker\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 44, in load_backend
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django_postgrespool' isn't an available database backend.
Try using django.db.backends.XXX, where XXX is one of:
    'dummy', 'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'sqlite3'
Error was: cannot import name Diagnostics
```

Of course I checked I can `import django_postgrespool` in the same env.
I found [this similar issue](https://github.com/kennethreitz/django-postgrespool/issues/6), however its resolution was to use django 1.4+ and I'm using 1.4.3

Comment: This error still persists using the recommended versions in the tutorial: dj-database-url 0.3.0, 
Django 1.8.1, 
django-postgrespool 0.3.0, 
gunicorn 19.3.0, 
psycopg2 2.6, 
SQLAlchemy 1.0.4, 
whitenoise 1.0.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstall psycopg2-2.5.1 and install [psycopg2-2.4.6](http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/2.4.6/psycopg2-2.4.6.win-amd64-py2.7-pg9.2.2-release.exe).

I don't know why it solves this problem, when psycopg2-2.5.1 is a requirement of the latest postgrespool. I am using Windows Python 2.7.3 AMD64.
I've [reported this as a bug](https://github.com/kennethreitz/django-postgrespool/issues/17) to django-postgrespool

Comment: This answer didn't solve the problem to me. I removed my current psycopg version (2.6, as recommended in Heroku's Python tutorial), installed version 2.4.6 but nothing changes. The error still persists.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution that using psycopg2-2.6.1 instead of psycopg2-2.6.

I adjusted the version number in requirement.txt from 2.6 to 2.6.1 and everything is done!